# Add key and value to array if it doesnt exist

Tags: php

So I have an Array called $sales that consits of objects like:

```
"DR22" => array:3 [▼
    "brand" => "DR22"
    "year" => "0"
    "last_year" => null
  ]
  "FGIPA46C" => array:3 [▼
    "brand" => "FGIPA46C"
    "month" => "3"
    "year" => "3"
  ]
```

Now each one should have "Month" "Year" "Last Year" "Last Month" but if there is no sale its not in there, which i get, but if it doesnt exist I just want to add it with 0 value. I tried:

```
    foreach ($sales as $sale)
    {  
        if (empty($sale['month'])) {
            $sale['month'] = 0;
        }
    }
```

But it doesnt add anything. Spits out the same.

Comment: `foreach ($sales as &$sale)` See that `&`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php i use that in my job applicant  testing

Comment: he means i dose not add `$sale['month']` in to the exiting array @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($sales as &$sale) {if (empty($sale['month']))        { $sale['month'] = 0; }}
```

You need to pass the $sale array by reference (using the &).  This will mean that the original $sales array is updated

Comment: Im writing on my phone. Tried formatting code but it won't work. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use array_map function, for example:

```
$array = array_map(function($item){
    if(empty($item["month"])){
        $item["month"] = 0;
    }
    return $item;
}, $array);
```